# How to calculate the distance from a pixel in the Lab-color space to a specific prototype

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, colors, javacv

I have `Lab-Image` and for each pixel in it, i want to know how Red, Green, Blue and Yellow that pixel is.

which means, for the input `Lab-Image` i should get four images one for Red,Green,Blue and Yellow.

as far as I researched, i knew that could be done by calculating the ecludian distance from each pixel in the `Lab-image` to the prototype of the color (R,G,B or Y). for an example, if i want to produce an image contains how Red the pixels in the `Lab-Image`, then for each pixel in the `Lab-Image`, i have to calculate the distance from that pixel in the `Lab-Image` to the prototype of the Red color in the `Lab-color space`

kindly please provide some advice and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is convert the color value you need (e.g.   Red = 255,0,0  in RGB) to Lab (Lref,aref,bref),   then calculate euclidean distance between each pixel and this value, and set the distance as the output pixel value.

`out_pixel=sqrt(sqr(Lpixel-Lref)+sqr(apixel-aref)+sqr(bpixel-bref))`

You may want to normalize the values, if you want the pixel output to fit in 0-255.

Comment: would you please tell me what is the value of "aref,bref" for an example?